# stop javascript to redirect after alert() function

Tags: javascript, alert

I am using javascript to check file size. If it is bigger than 1m it shows an alert and after that it redirect to index page.

I want know how to make it stay in the same page without redirect and without refresh and keep all page information inserted by user as it is.

This is the code:

```
if(fileInput.files[0].size > 1050000) {
    alert('File size is bigger than 1Mb!');
    return false;
}
```

the hole code:

```
var handleUpload = function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    var fileInput = document.getElementById('file');

    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('javascript', true);

    if(fileInput.files[0].size > 1050000) {
        //document.getElementById("image_id").innerHTML = "Image too big (max 1Mb)";
        alert('File bigger than 1Mb!');
        //window.location="upload.php";
        return false;
        }

    for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.files.length; ++i){

        data.append('file[]', fileInput.files[i]);

    }   

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
        if(event.lengthComputable){
            var percent = event.loaded / event.total;
            var progress = document.getElementById('upload_progress');

            while (progress.hasChildNodes()){
                progress.removeChild(progress.firstChild);
            }
            progress.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Math.round(percent * 100) +' %'));
            document.getElementById("loading-progress-17").style.width= Math.round(percent * 100) +'%';
        }
    });
    request.upload.addEventListener('load', function(event){
        document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'none';
    });
    request.upload.addEventListener('error', function(event){
        alert('Upload failed');
    });
    request.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event){
        if (this.readyState == 4){
            if(this.status == 200){
                var links = document.getElementById('uploaded');
                var uploaded = eval(this.response);
                var div, a;
                for (var i = 0; i < uploaded.length; ++i){
                    div = document.createElement('div');
                    a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.setAttribute('href', 'files/' + uploaded[i]);
                    a.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uploaded[i]));
                    div.appendChild(a);
                    links.appendChild(div);
                }
            }else{
                console.log('server replied with HTTP status ' + this.status);
            }
        }
    });
    request.open('POST', 'upload.php');
    request.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    document.getElementById('upload_progress').style.display = 'block';
    request.send(data);

}

window.addEventListener('load', function(event){

    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', handleUpload);
});
```

the upload.php code with the html

```
<?php
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){
        if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "files/{$name}")){
            $uploaded[] = $name;
        }
    }
    if(!empty($_POST['javascript'])){
        die(json_encode($uploaded));
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="upload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="uploaded">
            <?php

            if (!empty($uploaded)){
                foreach ($uploaded as $name){
                    echo '<div><a href="files/',$name,'">',$name,'</a></div>';
                }
            }

            ?>
             </div>
<div id="upload_progress"></div>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file" name="file[]" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the code that's doing the redirect.

Comment: after press ok in the alert box it redirect me to the index page

Comment: @Barmar need the page code?

Comment: It's hard to tell how to stop it from redirecting if we don't know how it's redirecting in the first place. Try to reduce it to just the minimum needed to understand what's happening.

Comment: @Barmar ok done if need the upload.php code tell me

Comment: Where is the redirect in the code you added?

Comment: @Barmar there is no redirect i don't know why it redirect . here is a part of php code  foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $key => $name){
  if ($_FILES['file']['error'][$key] == 0 && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$key], "files/{$name}")){
   $uploaded[] = $name;
  }
 }
 if(!empty($_POST['javascript'])){
  die(json_encode($uploaded));
 }

Comment: The PHP code is irrelevant, since you don't do the upload when the size check fails. What matters is the code that calls `handleupload()`, it must be doing the redirect.

Comment: Please add the HTML code that includes your form with the `#submit` item.

Comment: @Barmar i have uploaded the hole code

Answer (score 0):

You may get rid of `return` it should work. Else, maybe you should try modals instead of alerts. They are more neat and pretty

Comment: In that case try modals.

Answer (score 0):

Return false is preventing the redirect.

````
       var val = $("#inputId").val();      

        if (val >= 0 || val <=9)
        {           
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Enter Digits Only");
            return false;
        }
     ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Add `event.preventDefault();` below the alert function.
This may help you to stay on the same page.